# Bilinear Form and Matrix Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, bilinear-form

> Let $v \in T_2(V)$ be a bilinear form over finite space V. Let T be a
>    Linear transformation $V \to V$. We define: $v_T(x,y) = v(T(x),y)$.
>
> Assuming $v$ is nondegenerate, let us have another bilinear form $\xi
>  \in T_2(V)$. Prove that there exists exactly one transformation $T$ so
>    $\xi = v_T$.

${}$

My idea is trying to find T explicitly, by showing that if $v_T$ and $\xi$ operate the same on each two vectors in the basis $(e_i,e_j)$, than they must be equal.

Taking $v_T(e_i,e_j) = \sum_{i,j}\alpha_{ij}T(e_i)e_j = \sum_{i,j}\beta_{ij}e_ie_j = \xi(e_i,e_j)$ and defining $T$ so $T(e_i) = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\beta_{i1}}{\alpha_{i1}}\\
\frac{\beta_{i2}}{\alpha_{i2}}\\
\vdots \\
\frac{\beta_{in}}{\alpha_{in}}\\
\end{pmatrix}$
Thus making both of the sides equal.

I'm not sure whether this approach is correct. Also, I believe I used the nondegenerate fact at the point that for every vector in the basis $v_T \neq 0$ but I'm not sure exactly how it works formally.

Would love your help getting directions to solve this, and comments about my approach, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the fact that $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$ (where $^T$ denotes a transposed matrix), we get:
$$[x]^T[v_t][y] = ([T][x])^T[v][y] = [x]^T[T]^T[v][y] =[x]^T([v]^T[T])^T[y] $$ So, that brings us to:$$ [\xi]^T = [v]^T[T]$$

Notice $[v]$ is invertible, as $v$ is non-degenerate, so:
$$ [T]=([v]^T)^{-1}[\xi]^T$$